# Nginx with multiple docker-compose error 111

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I 'm trying to deploy a service with multiple docker-compose files using Nginx as reverse-proxy.
My folder structure is:

[image]

and my files are:

Apple docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  apples:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    networks:
      reverseproxy_santo-dio:
        aliases:
          # ApplesApp hostname on "fruit-network"
          - apples_net

networks:
  reverseproxy_santo-dio:
    external: true
```

Apple docker:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
RUN echo "<html><body><h1>A</h1>App A works!</body></html>" > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

Orange docker-compose:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  orange:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    networks:
     reverseproxy_santo-dio:
        aliases:
          - orange_net
      

networks:
  reverseproxy_santo-dio:
    external: true
```

Orange docker:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
RUN echo "<html><body><h1>B</h1>App B works!</body></html>" > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
```

My reverse-proxy is:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./log/:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - santo-dio
    restart: always


networks:
  santo-dio:
```

where the nginx.conf:

```
server {
  # Redirect http:// to https://
    listen 80; # default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mylog.error_log  debug;
    
     
    #frontend 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://apples_net;
    }

    #backend
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://orange_net:8080/api;
    }
  
}
```

To deploy the service I lauch:

1. reverse proxy
2. apple
3. orange

When I go in my browser apple (localhost) works but orange (localhost/api) answers me with **502 Bad Gateway.**
In my logfile:

> 2021/05/04 11:07:23 [error] 32#32: *4 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
> xxx.xxx.xx.x, server: , request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8080/api", host: "localhost"

Where is my error?
I started from this project: [multiple-docker-compose-same-ports](https://nicolasbouliane.com/blog/multiple-docker-compose-same-ports)

Thank

Comment: You `proxy_pass http://orange_net:8080`; is the "orange" container listening on that port, or the default HTTP port 80?

Comment: I think it uses the port 80, becose in the network it has "orange_net"  as alias. But if I use "http://orange_net:80" I get the same bad response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I had a problem with nginx.conf. I don't understand why

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://orange_net:8080/api;
    }
```

it doesn't works but patience. This setup is perfect for my purpose.

REVERSE-PROXY:

```
#/reverse-proxy/docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./log/:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - santo-dio
    restart: always


networks:
  santo-dio:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.10.0/16
```

--

```
#/reverse-proxy/nginx.conf
server {
  server_name apples_net.com;
  #resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s; # Local Docker DNS
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/apples_net.error_log  debug;

  location / {
    auth_request off;
    #proxy_pass http://apples_net:80;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.2:80;
  }
}

server {
  server_name orange_net.com;
  #resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5s; # Local Docker DNS
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/orange_net.error_log  debug;

  location / {
    auth_request off;
    #proxy_pass http://orange_net:80;
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.1:80;
    
  }
}
```

APPLES:

```
#/apples/docker-compose.yaml
#/apples/Dockerfile
version: "3.5"

services:
  apples:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      reverseproxy_santo-dio:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.10.2
        aliases:
          - apples_net

networks:
  reverseproxy_santo-dio:
    external: true
```

ORANGES:

```
#/oranges/docker-compose.yaml
#/oranges/Dockerfiles
version: "3.5"
services:
  orange:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # expose:
    #   - 8081
    networks:
     reverseproxy_santo-dio:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.10.1
        aliases:
          - orange_net
      

networks:
  reverseproxy_santo-dio:
    external: true
```

In this version I mapped the IP addresses of my applications. But it's possible to skip that step and just use aliases